# Remote MySql Database keeps on timing out

Tags: mysql

Whenever I try to connect to a database from another IP address to my Centos VPS server, I keep on getting connection refused error.

I have tried everything on Stack Overflow; including but not limited to adjusting the bind-address in the /etc/my.cnf file.

Also to note, my firewall is turned off. So I do not know why this is happening.

Comment: maybe the host blocked it before it got to the VPS? Is your MySQL username configured for remote logins? It would be helpful to have the exact error message (you can obfuscate your IP/hostname of course)

Comment: I am using cPanel, have everything setup on the cPanel side. I don't know how to do the server side.

Comment: cPanel _is_ the server side, effectively. It's the control panel for your server. From there you can usually set options for your MySQL server including whitelisting hosts/IP addresses for remote login (both at a server level, and a username level).

Comment: So if I whitelist the IP will it work?

Comment: maybe, if everything else is set up correctly. It'd be quicker to try it than to ask me :-) If the place you're connecting from has a dynamic IP though, you might have to keep changing the whitelist, so just be aware of that. P.S. I really would amend your earlier comment to remove the IP of the MySQL server, you don't want to attract speculative hackers. I did suggest that you obfuscate it before posting the error message.

Comment: I am trying to connect from another web server to this site.  I have whitelisted the ip address and it still does not work

Comment: just to check, you whitelisted the IP address of the other webserver, right? Not the IP of the MySQL server. And you still get the same error message?

Comment: Yes I whitelisted the ip address of the web  server

Comment: and the same error message still?

Comment: I am still getting the same error.

Comment: I am trying to connect to a shared hosting provider and I am using the shared ip address. Does that make a difference?

Comment: I thought you said the MySQL server was a VPS, not shared hosting? Please be clear.

Comment: I am trying to connecting my MySQL server (which is on the VPS) to a shared hosting via MySQL remote connection

Comment: So, to be clear, you want to connect _from_ a web application on shared hosting, _to_ a mysql server on a VPS? is that right?

Comment: Yes that is correct

Comment: Ok so in the cPanel for the **VPS** you need to whitelist the IP address or hostname of the **shared hosting**, to allow remote mysql connections. In the cPanel of the **shared hosting**, in "Server information", you should be able to find the correct IP address or hostname to put into the whitelist on the VPS.

Comment: @ADyson, I did all of that. It is still refusing to connect. Maybe it is because of the shared hosting is blocking all IP addresses coming in? The weird thing is that I am able to connect to the shared hosting database with no problems.

Comment: If that doesn't work, you'll have to ask the hosting providers of the VPS and the shared hosting respectively whether they actually support these kinds of connections or not, and ask for their help instead. They should each have a support desk to speak to, and maybe some documentation about what is or is not allowed on the account.

Comment: My VPS is unmanaged so they will not provide support of that nature.

Comment: I found the solution. Apparently my shared hosting provider does not support these matters. So, I am going to have to find another hosting.

Comment: That's annoying. But cheap hosts are often quite restrictive about what you can do. You could put all of it on the VPS I imagine?

Comment: Yes I can do that

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem is due to lack of support in the hosting environment

Comment: Okay thanks very much